# Set constraint for textview to the right of cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, textview, constraints, cell

I have got a `UITableView` with dynamic cells.
In each cell will be a small textview on the right side of the cell.

How can i set an constraint, which fixed this textview with a fix value of space to the right side of the cell in iOS8 Swift?

At the moment I only know, how I can set the space from textview to the left side of the cell, but I need to fix the space between textview and right side.

[image]

Comment: You should create a custom TableViewCell and there you can add the textview and manipulate the constraints.

Comment: okay i have create a custom TableViewCell. but how can i "manipulate" the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom TableViewCell or in your prototype add the textview and manipulate the constraints of XIB file in storyboard. What you can do is set for example the constraints of width and height and also set the Spacing to the right side and the top side.

[image]

Or, another thing you can do is: choose the textView and then press ctrl+LeftMouseClick and drug to the left into the cellView.Like this:

[image]

When you let the click choose "Center Vertically in Container" like this:

[image]

To "Center Horizontally in Container" do the same thing as above, but this time drug to the top, int o the container cellView again.

Comment: and why i need a custom table view cell for this? this way i can do it in a normal cell, too oO?

Comment: Yes you can do it also with the prototype. I thought you wanted to have the changes in a different custom cell that's why I mentioned. But yes, of course you can have that constraints with prototype.

Comment: okay, because your solution was the same way i have tested. but this is my problem anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285265/wrong-layout-after-swipe-delete-function